# Getting First Order Date for Each Customer

Tags: mysql

this one is driving me to drink so I would love some help.

I've got a table with:

```
act_Address, act_OrderID, act_Date
```

I'm trying to get the first act_Date for each address we shipped to.

Here's what I've tried but it's been running now for well over an hour so I'm thinking this isn't going to work...

```
SELECT c.act_Address,

(SELECT o.act_OrderID 
FROM tbl_Activity o 
WHERE c.act_Address = o.act_Address 
ORDER BY o.act_Date 
LIMIT 1) AS order_id, 

(SELECT d.act_Date
FROM tbl_Activity d 
WHERE c.act_Address = d.act_Address 
ORDER BY d.act_Date 
LIMIT 1) as order_date

FROM tbl_Activity c
```

I've got to be doing something very wrong, doesn't seem like getting the first date for an address would be that hard, but I'm not that smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query uses two correlated subqueries to get `act_Date` and `act_OrderID` values. Each subquery is executed once for every record of `tbl_Activity`.

You can use:

```
SELECT act_Address, MIN(act_Date) AS fist_Date
FROM tbl_Activity
GROUP BY act_Address
```

to get the first date per address. Then you can use the above query as a derived table and join back to the original table to get the rest of the fields:

```
SELECT t1.act_Address, t1.act_OrderID, t1.act_date
FROM tbl_Activity AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT act_Address, MIN(act_Date) AS fist_Date
   FROM tbl_Activity
   GROUP BY act_Address
) AS t2 ON t1.act_Address = t2.act_Address AND t1.act_Date = t2.first_Date
```

I also propose placing a composite index on `(act_Address, act_Date)`.

Comment: Giorgos, thanks so much. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `GROUP BY` in a subselect:

```
SELECT a.act_Address, a.act_OrderID, a.act_Date
FROM (
    SELECT a2.act_Address addr, MIN(a2.act_Date) mindate FROM tbl_Activity a2
    GROUP BY a2.act_Address
) g, tbl_Activity a
WHERE a.act_Address = g.addr AND a.act_Date = g.mindate;
```